# Connect multiple Roscores to one Stage instance

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i need to achieve a multi robot simulation in stage with several roscores. Is it possible to connect several roscores to one Stage instance ?
So Roscore1 -> Robot1
Roscore2 -> Robot2
Like it works by the MobileSim simulator for rosaria.

And i have to run each roboter in a own roscore, one big roscore is no option

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99561/connect-multiple-roscores-to-one-stage-instance/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-10**:
Please explain why one roscore is not an option?

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-11-11**:
The robots have a very unreliable network connection, and each robot needs to work on its own because they lose connection to the system, and it might take a long time until they reconnect again.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-11**:
If you have real robots how do you intend to use stage?

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2013-11-11**:
The development would be much faster (and may be easier) if we simulate the environment, so all developer can test their code if they want. Now we have bottelneck for testing code because we have just hardware for one robot system (but currently 3 different teams working on that system)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Especially if you have limited robot time I would highly recommend you consider allowing testing with the hardware not in the loop using the simulation.  For your use case with multiple teams

If you do want to continue to get 3 independent robots working with one master I recommend reading topics from the ROS MultiMaster SIG: http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Multimaster

The most active multimaster implementation is the [Robotics In Concert](http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_concert) it's actively being developed.  However the others implementations have proven useful for their designed use case.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0